# Как настроить подсказки по функциям javascript в phpstorm?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, ide

Добрый день!

1. Не получается настроить подсказки по документации javascript, всплывающие при клике CTRL+Q.

Почему то изначально они не установились, а по мануалам jetbrains не разобрался.

Они там дают ссылки на репозитории, но там лежат файлы в другом формате и виде, чем документация загруженная в шторм.

Сейчас какие-то пустые и убогие подсказки загружаются из папки \plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\lib\JavaScriptLanguage.jar!\com\intellij\lang\javascript\index\predefined\DOMCore.js

Посоветуйте хорошую документацию, со ссылками на web, и как ее установить.

2. также может быть посоветуете какие то русские варианты баз или просто английские хорошие по jquery

Comment: документация, доступная по CTRL+Q, берется из комментариев в файле, где определена данная функция. Соответственно, единственный способ как-то улучшить документацию - писать побольше комментариев в коде. Кстати, начиная с 2017.3, js стабы из `javascript\index\predefined` больше не используются - вместо них используются d.ts файлы из typescript репозитория

Comment: спасибо, но просто сильно отличается от шпаргалок по php, например. Практически пустые скупые подсказки и в websotm также все плохо. Я понимаю, что можно написать самому себе документацию, но неужели нет до сих пор готовой